# rlang::eval_tidy call with custom data object

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My goal is to create an object that behaves similar to a data frame. In order to use it in ggplot2 it has to mimic the interface for the [rlang::eval_tidy](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/eval_tidy) call.

The documentation states that the data argument can be either a data frame, named list or vector. And that alternatively a data mask can be created with `as_data_mask()` or `new_data_mask()`. In my case I don't want to change the code for ggplot, but the behavior of my object if it gets called as data argument in `eval_tidy`.

Is there a way to do so? In earlier versions of `rlang`there seems to be a generic function `as_dictionary()` for this purpose.

Comment: `as_data_pronoun`?

Comment: Have you tried writing an S3 method for fortify as in `fortify.myclass <- function(x){convert_to_a_data.frame(x)}` and see if that works out? Otherwise, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that I don't want to create an extra copy of the data frame, but use my structure. The fortify function for my data type behaves like the default data frame function and just returns the model.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to patch the `as_data_pronoun` to just print a string but it doesn't seem to be called: `package <- getNamespace('rlang'); unlockBinding('as_data_pronoun', package); package$as_data_pronoun <- function(x, y, z) UseMethod('as_data_pronoun', x); lockBinding('as_data_pronoun', package); as_data_pronoun.polyglot.value <- function(x, y, z) print('>>>>>>>>data mask<<<<<<<<<<<<'); as_data_pronoun.default <- function(x, y, z) .Call(rlang_as_data_pronoun, x)`

Comment: Right, no need to print it manually as far as I’m aware.

Comment: I just want to check if the function gets called. But that wasn't the case